# How to assert/expect if a function is called in Chai

Tags: node.js, chai, sinon-chai

I have a function like below which needs to be test with chai

```
export class GroupMessage {
 public async createTenant(): Promise<void> {
     const groupCreator = [];

     groupCreator.push(ServiceWrapper.Create(project));
     await Promise.all(groupCreator);
 }
  
}
```

To test this, I have the below test case

```
  it('createTenantshould return create tenant', async () => {
    sandbox.stub(ServiceWrapper, 'Create');


    const groupNtmMessage = new GroupMessage();
    GroupMessage.createTenant();
    expect(ServiceWrapper, 'Create').to.have.been.called;
  });
```

With the above code I get the below error

```
Error: Invalid Chai property: called. Did you mean "all"?
```

Any way we can test this, I have looked through chai documentation, but haven't found anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this. Instead of expect, sinon.assert can be used like below

```
sinon.assert.calledWith(ServiceWrapper.Create, 'test-project');
```